# Ошибка при использовании JSTL

Tags: java, jstl

При переходе на JSP страницу, которая использует JSTL получаю ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`dependency` в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

(`<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>` так же не работает)

JSP страница:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Error</title>
    <style><%@ include file="/frontend/style/style.css"%></style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="error">
    <div class="error__img"><img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/frontend/images/error.png" alt=""></div>
    <p class='error__sorry'><c:out value="We are very sorry"/></p>
    <form action="hotel" method="post" class="error__back">
        <button type="submit" name="command" value="toMainPage">Back to main page</button>
    </form>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура проекта, если это важно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно смотреть лог сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Для apache tomcat версии 10 (возможно когда вы это смотрите уже версии >10) нужно использовать

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```